# This code throwing a hydration error next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

Why does this code throw a hydration error in NextJS? The type of Items is an array of ReactNode's. What would you suggest as an alternative. I have tried searching for info, but I haven't found anything with NextJs.

```
<tbody className={className}>
  {Items.map((Item) => {
    return (
      <tr
        className="grid gap-[1px] items-center"
        style={{ gridTemplateColumns: columns }}
      >
        {Item}
      </tr>
    );
  })}
</tbody>
```

Comment: Please share the error message or screenshot

Comment: Can you show us the code for the components you're rendering as `Item`?

Comment: Has most probably something to do with invalid nestings of HTML tags.  What's in `Item`, especially what tags are you rendering?

Answer (score 0):

There is no key for each iteration and and also `style={{ gridTemplateColumns: columns }}` does not exist.  Ussually Hydation error occurs when the css is faulty.

```
<tbody className={className}>
  {Items.map((Item) => {
    return (
      <tr
        className="grid gap-[1px] grid-cols-3"
     
      >
        {Item}
      </tr>
    );
  })}
</tbody>
```

Comment: columns is a generated string stored inside of a state, and I commented {Item} out and it worked fine so I don’t think that is the issue.